# How to convert user entered datetime to milliseconds

Tags: django

I am trying to convert user entered datetime to milliseconds. Here i'm using template file for user to enter date time. And i'm extracting and stored in variable from and to.How to convert that into milliseconds.

```
from = request.POST.get('from_date')
to = request.POST.get('to_date')
```

Comment: Please use a `Form` for this. You can then retrieve this as `datetime` objects, and convert it to milliseconds.

Comment: I'm getting value. But after that how to convert that into milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For converting datetime to milliseconds:

Python 3:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_obj = datetime.today()
datetime_millisec = datetime_obj.timestamp() * 1000
```

Python 2.7:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_obj = datetime.today()
# convert into seconds and then multiply by 1000
datetime_millisec = int(datetime_obj.strftime('%s')) * 1000
```

For calculating the datetime difference in milliseconds:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
time_diff = from_date - to_date // assuming from_date and to_date are datetime objects
time_diff_millisec = time_diff.total_seconds() * 1000
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is for current date time right? assume 2018/12/12 10:30:56. from variable holds this date time.How to do this.

Comment: @Kumar I just took an example where its of datetime object. If your `variable` holds the value as `string` then you can convert it to `datetime` object using `strptime`. i.e. datetime.strptime("2018/12/12 10:30:56", "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S").